# Using Stash to share data between templates

Tags: stash

Is it possible to Stash some content in one template and then grab it from another template?

Basically, I want to store a bunch of Entry IDs in one template and then i'm AJAX loading another template where I would like to retrieve those Entry IDs and use them to plot markers on a map.

I've tried using scope, but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
{exp:stash:set name="show_nearby" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2" parse="inward" trim="yes" scope="user" refresh="10"}
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_4}"}
        {exp:trails_nearby entry_id="{entry_id}" lat="{thingtodo_latitude}" lng="{thingtodo_longitude}"}
    {/exp:channel:entries}  
{/exp:stash:set}
```

The following code gets the values above when used in the same template (so I know the values are being set;

```
{exp:stash:get name="show_nearby" backspace="1"}
```

However, when I use in another template it just returns everything from the channel because the entry_id isn't being set;

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="things-to-do" entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='show_nearby' backspace='1' scope='user'}" parse="inward" status="open" dynamic="no"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your AJAX call? if the `{exp:stash:set...}` is working without AJAX, I'd assume your JS isn't. When you say 'returns everything' I assume your filters aren't being applied, can you debug the POST data and share that as well?

Comment: Hey @adamell. The ajax is simply loading another template rather than passing any data to it

Comment: Try adding save="yes" in parameters with scope site or user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Romans-8---31-39. That did the trick using scope site.